# what goes in what? Frame, Pane, Button, Label, Container ectr

Tags: java, user-interface, types

I just have a small problem with setting up the GUI. (java 1.7, javafx)

```
- The method addAll(Node...) in the type ObservableList<Node> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Container)
```

In code context:

```
Frame f = new Frame();
Frame g = new Frame();
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(f , g);
```

What i want to know... what goes in what? O_o  here are the used types:  Frame, Button, Container, HBox, BorderPane, Pane, Stage, Scene, Label, VBox. And anything else you would be willing to add.

Sorry, for the basic question, but as someone, who has only done C and C++ till this point, it seems confusing, especially since the older answers have JFrame and JPane and the like.
Also is there a nother command I should use instead of `.add()`
Thank you all, for taking your time to help me.

Comment: "older answers have JFrame and JPane" - yeah, because they use Swing, and *NOT* AWT. Unless you are building an *applet* you should not be using the AWT classes directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error says that Frame is not a Node from JavaFX, instead it's a Container from AWT.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?javafx/scene/Node.html

'addAll' Needs a Node as parameter, not a Frame.

Your problem is that you're mixing libraries.